# Adding extra column and row to count sum() of each table row and column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Currently I have 2 tables in mysql which are listings table and agents table. The listings table holds all statuses, refno and an agent_id that operates with that particular product. Now the names for these agents are stored in my agents table. So to reference the agents name with a particular listing, I use `inner join` agents table and check all entries where `agent_id = id`. This gives me the correct output.

Now I am retrieving the count of all statuses of each product with their respective agents using:

```
select SUM(t.status = 'D' ) AS draft,
    SUM(t.status = 'N' ) AS unpublish,
    SUM(t.status = 'Y' ) AS publish,
    SUM(t.status = 'S' ) AS sold,
    SUM(t.status = 'T' ) AS let, c.name
    FROM listings t INNER JOIN agents c ON t.agent_id = c.id
    GROUP BY t.agent_id
```

But now I want an extra row and column that counts total of the data in each row and each column.
Something like this:

[image]

Link to dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1f7ce90a0562b75f62641272ccf1a93

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Comment: Yea it says mysqli in my phpmyadmin

Comment: If it is MySql then WITH ROLLUP should work. Execute `select @@version;` to be sure.

Comment: It says 10.4.21-MariaDB

Comment: WITH ROLLUP works in MariaDB.

Comment: @forpas I changed the query a bit, I removed the semi colon in COALESCE(c.name, 'Total') AS name; and replaced it with , because otherwise it gave this error: imgur.com/a/Xn59ieF Is that the problem?

Comment: No, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply sum together the 5 current boolean expressions:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(c.name, 'Total') AS name,
    SUM(t.status = 'D') AS draft,
    SUM(t.status = 'N') AS unpublish,
    SUM(t.status = 'Y') AS publish,
    SUM(t.status = 'S') AS sold,
    SUM(t.status = 'T') AS let,
    SUM(t.status = 'D') + SUM(t.status = 'N') + SUM(t.status = 'Y') +
    SUM(t.status = 'S') + SUM(t.status = 'T') AS Total
FROM listings t 
INNER JOIN agents c
    ON t.agent_id = c.id
GROUP BY
    t.agent_id
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Yes okay, so this gave me the row wise sum, but I also want it column wise. Would that be possible in this same statement

Comment: Oops misread your requirement, you must sum the boolean expressions in this case.

Comment: So would that be possible in this same statement for having a column total?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: So if you see the picture I added in my question, the last row shows a column wise total as well, which I'm trying to get

Comment: ...did you actually try my updated answer?

Comment: Yes and it gives me the correct output for the row wise total, But I'm not getting the total of each column like the one shown in the last row of my picture

Comment: @JayModi OK, try using `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`, see the updated answer above.

Comment: I tried this and it gave this error: https://imgur.com/a/oHYarif

Comment: I somehow doubt that you are really using MySQL.

Comment: No I am using mysqli. I also changed your query a bit, I removed the semi colon in COALESCE(c.name, 'Total') AS name; and replaced it with , because otherwise it gave this error: https://imgur.com/a/Xn59ieF

Comment: Hey could you kindly check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69626594/showing-all-data-in-a-datewise-order-grouped-by-dates