# Returning query in a row wise format instead of column

Tags: mysql

Currently I have 2 tables, a listing table and a logs table. With the following query I'm trying to get the listings of a product on a particular day, and it returns the right output.

```
with X as (
  select 
    l.*,
    (select status_from from logs where logs.refno = l.refno and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-01' order by logs.logtime limit 1) logstat
  from listings l
  where l.added_date < '2021-10-01'
)
, Y as (select X.*, ifnull(X.logstat, X.status) stat from X)
SELECT 
  status.text,
  COUNT(Y.id) AS c 
from status
left join Y on Y.stat = status.code
group by status.code, status.text;
```

This gives an output like this:

[image]

Here I've filtered the query by 1 date which in this case is 2021-10-01. The output should look like:

| Publish | Action | Let | Sold | Draft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e0b8d484a41ac9104d0fb002e7f9a3c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query -

```
with X as (
  select 
    l.*,
    (select status_from from logs where logs.refno = l.refno and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-02' order by logs.logtime limit 1) logstat
  from listings l
  where l.added_date between '2021-10-01 00:00:00' and '2021-10-02 00:00:00'      -- Start and end date range.
)
, Y as (select X.*, ifnull(X.logstat, X.status) stat20211001 from X)
SELECT 
  added_date,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status.text = 'Publish' THEN Y.id END) AS Publish,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status.text = 'Action' THEN Y.id END) AS Action,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status.text = 'Let' THEN Y.id END) AS Let,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status.text = 'Sold' THEN Y.id END) AS Sold,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status.text = 'Draft' THEN Y.id END) AS Draft
from status
join Y on Y.stat20211001 = status.code
group by added_date;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9befa247f51dde75f5145350b2558ce3)

Comment: No this doesn't give the right output. I've tried putting '2021-10-01' and '2021-10-02' as the dates with your query and it does not return the output I've shown in my table in the question

Comment: @JayModi, Please try the edited code. Actually you have the addeddate as timestamp and I have used the input as Date only.

Comment: I still cant get the right result. Do you want to move this conversation to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238314/doubt-clearing